# Error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" produced

Tags: c++

I get top error in below code in line `channels[0][x] = luma_lut[row[x]];` :

```
typedef struct {
    const unsigned char *const *const row_pointers;
    float gamma_lut[256];
} image_data;
void convert_image_row_gray(const float * __restrict channels[], const int num_channels, const int y, const int width, void * user_data)
{
    image_data *im = (image_data*)user_data;
    const unsigned char *row = im->row_pointers[y];
    const float *luma_lut = im->gamma_lut; // init converts it

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        channels[0][x] = luma_lut[row[x]];
    }
}
```

What's wrong in this code?

Comment: The pointer is declared with the qualifier const:  const float * __restrict channels[], So  you may not change the pointed objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`channels` is declared with `const float **` type, which means that `channels[i][j]` is an lvalue of `const float` type. You are not allowed to change `const float` lvalues - they are `const`.

Given this declaration of `channels` you can change `channels` itself, you can change `channels[i]`, but you cannot change `channels[i][j]`.